# VBA PowerPoint Slides set custom layout to refresh the layout

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created a script processing many slides and at the end, some slides seem to have glitches in their layout. For example, slide numbers have moved on some slides but not on others. It can be fixed manually by re-assigned the custom layout to the slide.

How can I do this automatically?

I could just loop over all slides, find out it's custom layout and re-assign it. But how? This code seems to loop infinitely:

```
Dim sld As Slide
Dim layoutName As String
Dim layoutIndex As Integer

       Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide 
       layoutName = sld.CustomLayout.Name
       layoutIndex = getLayoutIndexByName(layoutName)
       ActivePresentation.Slides(y).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(y).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(layoutIndex) 


Function getLayoutIndexByName(xName As String) As Integer
   ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Item (1)
   With ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
      For i = 1 To .Count
        Debug.Print ("inLoop Name: " + .Item(i).Name)
        If .Item(i).Name = xName Then
        getLayoutIndexByName = i
        Exit Function
        End If
   Next
   End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply reapply the layout already assigned, you only need this:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(y).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(y).CustomLayout
```

Occasionally, that command doesn't work, then this workaround is worth a try:

```
DoEvents
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SlideReset")
DoEvents
```

To apply a new layout, then you need to use something like this code, which is pretty similar to yours:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(y).CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(GetLayoutIndexFromName("Text Page", ActivePresentation.Designs(1)))
```

My version of GetLayoutIndexFromName:

```
Function GetLayoutIndexFromName(sLayoutName As String, oDes As Design) As Long
  Dim x As Long
  For x = 1 To oDes.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Count
    If oDes.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(x).Name = sLayoutName Then
      GetLayoutIndexFromName = x
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, John! The simple solution already helped me to find a way to solve the problem. :)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I appreciate an upvote.

Comment: I have tried but "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." Unfortunately, my account is too new. I am sorry!